# How to perform authorization of roles?

Tags: asp.net, roles

I have to map users into their roles in ASP.NET.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ASP.NET Membership subsystem: [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

Also check out www.asp.net for lots of excellent resources, including:

- [Securing your Web Site with Membership and Login Controls](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-06.aspx)
- [How Do I: Secure my Site using Membership and Roles?](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-45.aspx)